# Scrapy: How to get processed pipeline items from crawler?

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a Scrapy Crawler with several pipeline steps. The Crawler is part of a bigger framework which requires the crawler to return a list of the parsed items.

In Scrapy I implemented a pipeline containing several normalization steps. As Scrapy is part of the bigger framework - it would be great if I could return the items to the crawler and/or the framework after passed through the whole pipeline. Is there a way to accomplish this?

E.g. some pseudo code

```
url = 'http://somewebsite.com'
crawler = MyCrawler(url)
# each parsed website passes each pipeline step and is yielded / returned.
all_items_from_pipeline = crawler.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this the functional way, because Scrapy is asynchronous. But you can save the items in a file or database and then the other component can take them from there.

You also get the benefit that the items can be stored there until needed.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a deferred object from the crawler?